# Generating a partial view from another controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, partial-views

I read on StackOverflow that this syntax can be used in a view to generate a partial view from another controller:

```
@Html.Partial("~/[controllerX]/[actionY]", [model])
```

When I use it I get the following error message:

```
The partial view '~/[controllerX]/[actionY]' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:~/[controllerX]/[actionY]
```

If I use the url in a browser, the controller appear to work fine
http://[mydomain]/[controllerX] (Index action works.)
http://[mydomain]/[controllerX]/[actionY]?[someParameters] (Partial view is perfectly generated.

Thank you if you can help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
@Html.Action("[actionY]","[controllerX]",[model])
```

gave me the expected results.